# Oracle 11g / WAMP / Symfony3

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, oracle11g, wamp

It's the first time I work with Symfony and Oracle, I have a problem to connect a Oracle11g database to WAMP, I have tried a lot of tutorials but no one work.

I have enabled the `php_pdo_oci` extension in WAMP. I have downloaded the `Oracle client 32bit: Version 11.2.0.4.0`, put the files in `c:\instantclient_11_2` and add it to `PATH`.

I have configured `parameters.yml` and `config.yml` but when I try to do a request I get the error:

> "CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: "An exception occured in driver: could not find driver" at ...\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractOracleDriver.php line 76"

I'm on Windows 7 Pro 64, WAMP 32.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install pdo_oci8 driver and configure your paramaters.yml like this :

```
   parameters:
        database_driver: oci8
        database_host: hostname
        database_port: '1521'
        database_name: dbname
        database_user: username
```

Comment: I have installed php_oci8_11g.dll, it's work fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install php_oci8_11g.dll

First, i have moved to a 64bit version of WAMP.

-Download the "Instant Client Package - Basic" for Windows.Choose your version(64 bit) for me.

-Unzip it to c:\instantclient_11_2

-Edit the PATH environment setting and add c:\instant_11_2 before any other Oracle directories (to be sure put it on the begin of the variable)

-Restart your computer for environment variables to effect

-Now go to your php.ini file and add/uncomment the line

extension=php_oci8_11g.dll

-Save php.ini file

-Download the actual Thread Safe OCI-DLLs from pecl.php.net choose your version (I'm using PHP 5.6 so i get the 2.0.12)

-Unzip OCI-DLLs Zip file and copy all files from this folder to Extensions directory of PHP (php/ext)

-Restart WAMP